# Serial Communication data problem between Windows and embedded System (STM32) (C/C++)

Tags: windows, serial-port, microcontroller, stm32, serial-communication

I currently try to set up communication between a Windows program and a µC.
I'll show you the code to initialize the port:

```
int serialCommunication::serialInit(void){

//non overlapped communication
hComm = CreateFile( gszPort.c_str(),
                    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                    0,
                    0,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    0,
                    0);

if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    cout << "Error opening port." << endl;
    return 0;
}
else{
    cout << "Opened Port successfully." << endl;
}

if (SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR) == FALSE){
    cout << "Error setting communications mask." << endl;
    return 0;
}
else{
    SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR);
    cout << "Communications mask set successfully." << endl;
}

if (GetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams) == FALSE){
    cout << "Error getting CommState." << endl;
    return 0;
}
else{
    GetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);
    cout << "CommState retrieved successfully" << endl;
}

dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_115200;    // Setting BaudRate = 115200
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;             // Setting ByteSize = 8
dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;    // Setting StopBits = 1
dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;        // Setting Parity = None

if (SetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams) == FALSE){
    cout << "Error setting CommState" << endl;
    return 0;
}
else{
    SetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);
    cout << "CommState set successfully" << endl << endl;
    cout << "+---CommState Parameters---+" << endl;
    cout << "Baudrate = " << dcbSerialParams.BaudRate << endl;
    cout << "ByteSize = " << static_cast<int>(dcbSerialParams.ByteSize) << endl; //static Cast, um int auszugeben und kein char
    cout << "StopBits = " << static_cast<int>(dcbSerialParams.StopBits) << endl; //static Cast, um int auszugeben und kein char
    cout << "Parity = " << static_cast<int>(dcbSerialParams.Parity) << endl; //static Cast, um int auszugeben und kein char
    cout << "+--------------------------+" << endl;
}

/*------------------------------------ Setting Timeouts --------------------------------------------------*/

timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout         = 50;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant    = 50;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier  = 10;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant   = 50;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;

if (SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &timeouts) == FALSE){
    cout << "Error setting timeouts" << endl;
    return 0;
}
else{
    SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &timeouts);
    cout << "Timeouts set successfully." << endl;
    cout << "+--------------------------+" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

My Read function looks like this:

```
void serialCommunication::serialRead(void){
bool readStatus;
bool purgeStatus = 0;
bool correctData = 0;

cout << "Waiting for Data..." << endl; // Programm waits and blocks Port (like Polling)
readStatus = WaitCommEvent(hComm, &dwEventMask, 0);
if (readStatus == FALSE){
    cout << "Error in setting WaitCommEvent." << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "Data received." << endl;
    do{
        readStatus = ReadFile(hComm, &TempChar, sizeof(TempChar), &NoBytesRead, 0);
        SerialBuffer += TempChar; // add tempchar to the string
    }while (NoBytesRead > 0);
SerialBuffer.pop_back(); // Delete last sign in buffer, otherwise one "0" too much shows up, for example "23900" instead of "2390"
cout << endl << SerialBuffer << endl;
SerialBuffer = ""; // Reset string
}
```

So at some point, my µC sends the String "Init complete...!\r\n" after initializing some things. This works well.[Init complete proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Mp3.png)

Now after that, the communcation produces errors. I am getting Data I should not receive. The µC can only send data, if a specific string is sent to it by the PC. While debugging I could detect, that the µC never receives this specific string and therefore never sends data. In the following picture, I show you what gibberish I am receiving constantly though.
[Receiving Gibberish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Qvb.png)
/EDIT: I am constantly receiving the same gibberish

The funny thing is, I even receive that data, when the µC is completely switched off (Serial Cables are still connected). So there has to be some data at the port, which just is not deleted. I tried to restart the PC aswell, but it didn't help either.

I will also show you my while loop on PC:

```
while (testAbbruch != 1){
    pointer = acMessung(anzahlMessungen, average); // measurement with external multimeter
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Average: " << average << endl << endl;

    if (average >= 30){
        testAbbruch = 1; // there won't be a next while iteration
        befehl = "stopCalibration\r\n";
        serialTest.serialWrite(befehl);
        serialTest.serialRead();
    }
    else{
        cout << "Aktion: ";
        std::getline (cin, befehl);
        befehl = "increment"; //for debugging

        if (befehl == "increment"){
            befehl.append("\r\n"); // adding it, so the µC can detect the string correctly
            serialTest.serialWrite(befehl);
            serialTest.serialRead(); // µC has to answer
        }
        else if(befehl == "decrement"){
            befehl.append("\r\n"); // adding it, so the µC can detect the string correctly
            serialTest.serialWrite(befehl);
            serialTest.serialRead(); // µC has to answer
        }
        befehl = ""; // string leeren für nächsten Aufruf
    }
}
```

I know my program is far from perfect, but if I understood the serial Communication with Windows correctly, the buffer is deleted while reading.
Is there any clue you could give me?

EDIT// I just wrote a program that expects one of two inputs: One input is called "increment" the other one is called "decrement". Those inputs are sent to the µC via the serial communication port. Every time I try to send "increment" and instantly after that I am reading from the port, I receive the weird data from [this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxIIL.png) Now, every time I try to send "decrement" and instantly after that I am reading from the port, I receive the weird data from [that picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4bZY.png).
//

So my guess is that the data somehow is changed and then looped back to the PC? But why and how?!

Comment: Edit: I checked the settings like BaudRate, Paritybits etc. on both ends and they equal each other. I just can't figure out why I always receive corrupted data at my port except for the "Init complete" ...

Comment: I edited something I found out in the original post, maybe it might help with the solution

Comment: I also tried using another Port by using another USB connection. Still the same issue